# Parameter options for User Defined Functions in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Hi i have been trying to make a user defined function that allows the user to select the values which the function will use from a list.

I have tried setting the parameter i want as a list to type list in my function but this only seems to accept columns rather than a list of values a user can select from.

```
let
ListOfDays = {1.1,0.5,2,3,1},
DayOfTheWeek = (Day as list, HoursWorked ) =>
 let
    Earnings = Day * HoursWorked
 in
    Earnings

in
DayOfTheWeek
```

What i would like is for me to allow the user to select a single value from the ListOfDays list. I used typed list within my function parameters so that it can give the user a dropdown list kind of option.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this in PowerQuery (as opposed to DAX). Are you expecting the user to open the PBIX and go into the query editor?

Comment: @AlexisOlson i am creating a custom data connector, these are written in M

Comment: Are you expecting the user to open the PBIX and go into the query editor?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I am not sure where you are going with this

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if you aren't, then you've got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AlexisOlson i still dont see how it is an XY problem, either way i told you i am creating a custom data connector i didnt say anything about anyone entering using the power query editor

Comment: You're talking about user interaction but users can't interact with PowerQuery except through the desktop editor. I don't understand why my question is difficult to answer.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I suggest you look up what custom data connectors are, i have been answering your question and repeating myself. Its not that your question is difficult its just that you are failing to comprehend what i am doing.

Comment: You didn't once answer the question I asked. You mentioned a user choosing values from a dropdown and I'm trying to determine where you intend that dropdown to exist. Does it exist in the query editor? Is it a slicer on a report? In an external source that you are connecting to? The answer will be completely different depending on the context so I'm trying to determine that context.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Ideally it would be a dropdown within the data connector, I think the issue here is you are not familiar with data connectors; i have been trying to tell you that i am creating a custom data connector ever since you first asked your question, a data connector allows you to modify the way people interact with their data sources, though i suggest you read up on it as i can't go into the details here. If you can help me it would be nice to have your two cents, though if you are not familiar with data connectors then it may be hard to understand or answer my question.

Comment: Though I haven't used data connectors myself I have actually read about them and I've answered more questions than anyone else in each of the tags you've used so I'm not shooting entirely blind. There's a good chance that if I understand exactly what you're asking I can figure it out even if I don't immediately know the answer. Usually, a "user" tends to be a consumer of a published report so it was unclear to me how they interact with the connector itself. Given that you want a dropdown in the data connector, your "user" is creating reports and the answer is "yes" to my original question?

Comment: No because i am not expecting the user to open up power query editor, though the part about the user creating a table based on their interaction with the data connector is right. Nonetheless as far as i am concerned this isn't an XY issue, it's more of a; i would like to know if anyone knows how the dropdowm is achieved since theres limited resources out there that cover this part of the M user defined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is able to open up the Query Editor, then they can choose a `Day` parameter from a dropdown list and have this automatically apply to the query.

You would create the parameter from the Manage Parameters > New Parameter menu

[image: Manage Param]

The drop-down at the upper right of the image is how the user would select the choice.

Your User Defined Function `fn_DayOfTheWeek` would be the following:

```
let
   DayOfTheWeek = (Day as number, HoursWorked as number) =>
   let
      Earnings = Day * HoursWorked
   in
      Earnings
in
   DayOfTheWeek
```

Note that `Day` is a number, not a list. You want to choose from a list, not pass a list into the function.

Now you can invoke your function with your parameter to actually produce a result.

```
let
    Source = fn_DayOfTheWeek(Day, <HoursWorked value here>)
in
    Source
```

This result will update when you change the parameter.

As you can see, whether a user has access to the Query Editor is rather a critical question for this approach. I'm not sure if it's possible to somehow set a parameter directly within a custom connector dialog box or not but this should be equivalent in functionality.

Comment: Though this does work and therefore answers the question to some degree, i was generally looking for a way to achieve this through M. Since there's a lack of documentation on what user defined functions can do and so on. I used list as a parameter as an example of something close to what i would like to do. Though i am starting to think it may not be possible in M, regardless of this i have seen many data connectors with interesting functionality and user interaction, though as hard as i try i can not find anything on how they achieved their results.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the relevant documentation you are looking for:
[github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/docs/function-docs.md: **Adding Function Documentation**](https://github.com/microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/dbd99078501897e04e7a6b9305ad7857ae1b7a63/docs/function-docs.md)

In particular, look at the definition for `Documentation.AllowedValues`:

> List of valid values for this parameter. Providing this field will change the input from a textbox to a drop down list. Note, this does not prevent a user from manually editing the query to supply alternate values.

This (and other `Documentation` fields) are part of the meta typing of the function arguments. Scroll down to the code snippet which shows how to use them:

```
[DataSource.Kind="HelloWorldWithDocs", Publish="HelloWorldWithDocs.Publish"]
shared HelloWorldWithDocs.Contents = Value.ReplaceType(HelloWorldImpl, HelloWorldType);

HelloWorldType = type function (
    message as (type text meta [
        Documentation.FieldCaption = "Message",
        Documentation.FieldDescription = "Text to display",
        Documentation.SampleValues = {"Hello world", "Hola mundo"}
    ]),
    optional count as (type number meta [
        Documentation.FieldCaption = "Count",
        Documentation.FieldDescription = "Number of times to repeat the message",
        Documentation.AllowedValues = { 1, 2, 3 }
    ]))
    as table meta [
        Documentation.Name = "Hello - Name",
        Documentation.LongDescription = "Hello - Long Description",
        Documentation.Examples = {[
            Description = "Returns a table with 'Hello world' repeated 2 times",
            Code = "HelloWorldWithDocs.Contents(""Hello world"", 2)",
            Result = "#table({""Column1""}, {{""Hello world""}, {""Hello world""}})"
        ],[
            Description = "Another example, new message, new count!",
            Code = "HelloWorldWithDocs.Contents(""Goodbye"", 1)",
            Result = "#table({""Column1""}, {{""Goodbye""}})"
        ]}
    ];

HelloWorldImpl = (message as text, optional count as number) as table =>
    let
        _count = if (count <> null) then count else 5,
        listOfMessages = List.Repeat({message}, _count),
        table = Table.FromList(listOfMessages, Splitter.SplitByNothing())
    in
        table;
```

They also provide a screenshot of what this should look like when invoked:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I know this isnt standard here but i really appreciate this, so thank you!. I wish i could upvote this twice